# Can anyone please identify this beauty?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Obviously a German experimental flying boat. [image]

Comment: Just use Google Image search and you will find “Oertz W.6 Flugschooner”

Answer (score 6):

This is an [**Oertz W6 Flugschoner**](https://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft29904.htm) ([source](https://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft29904.htm)) or "Flying Schooner", a 1916 tandem biplane.

> The plane took off and landed well, but had problems with control in
> flight, so a second pair of ailerons was soon added between the rear
> wings. Formally, the design task was completed - the boat had a
> slightly greater estimated range than its predecessors, but for 1917
> these indicators were more than mediocre. In addition, although armed
> with two machine guns, due to its clumsiness the vehicle was an
> excellent target for new fighters. For these reasons, the boat did not
> find use in the fleet and was dismantled soon after testing.

[source](https://seawarpeace-ru.translate.goog/deutsch/seaplane/01_main/oertz_w6.html?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=ru&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=sc)

[image: Oertz W6 Flugschoner] ([source](https://flyingmachines.ru/Site2/Crafts/Craft29904.htm))

Comment: Thank you very much.